# Fatal error: Not enough bits to represent the passed value (Int16) in Swift

Tags: swift

I am translating a library from Java (Android) to -> Swift (iPhone)

Java code, works ok:

```
   long a = 48590108397870l;
   short b = ((short)(a & 65535));//b == -28370
```

Swift code:

```
    let a : Int64  = 48590108397870
    let b: Int16 = Int16(a & 65535)//Fatal error: Not enough bits to represent the passed value
```

Comment: different languages have different type promotion and casting rules... so what exactly is your question? Do you wonder why you get this exception?

Comment: @Hulk What do you mean with "type promotion rules"

Comment: e.g. this in java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`a & 65535` is a value between 0 and 2<sup>16</sup>-1, which fits in an `UInt16`, but not in an `Int16`. Contrary to many other languages, Swift does not truncate values implicitly.

Integers have an [`init(truncatingIfNeeded:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger/2925529-init) initializer which does what you want:

> When the bit width of T (the type of source) is equal to or greater than this type’s bit width, the result is the truncated least-significant bits of source.

Example:

```
let a : Int64 = 48590108397870
let b = Int16(truncatingIfNeeded: a)
print(b) // -28370
```

Another option is to create an unsigned integer first, which is then  converted to a signed integer with the same bit pattern:

```
let a : Int64 = 48590108397870
let b = Int16(bitPattern: UInt16(a & 0xFFFF))
print(b) // -28370
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on mine, +1 because this looks much safer/future-proof.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`withUnsafeBytes(of:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2998148-withunsafebytes) to convert the types.

Code:

```
let a: Int64 = 48590108397870
let b = a & 65535

let c: Int16? = withUnsafeBytes(of: b) { ptr -> Int16? in
    let binded = ptr.bindMemory(to: Int16.self)
    return binded.first
}

print("c: \(c)")
// Prints: c: Optional(-28370)
```

Comment: This works if the byte order is little endian. That is the case on all current platforms on which Swift runs, but I would not rely on it.